# ( was unexpected at this time (If exist folder)

Tags: batch-file

It's saying "( was unexpected at this time" the code:

```
:new_game
set /p name=Enter your name:

if exist Save\%name%\ (

echo This save exists delete it?
set /p var=[Y,N]

if %var% == N (
    goto new_game
) else ( 
    del /Q Save\%name%\
)
)
md Save\%name%\
```

It's up at the "if exist Save\%name%\ (".

Comment: Hmm - a small typo (shift-1 and shift-backtick are adjacent). The required character is `!` not `~`. That should make it work. Note however that you can also use `if /i ...` to make the `IF` case-insensitive. And since `%name%` may also contain spaces, it's safer to use `if exist "save\%name%"` - include the enclosing quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the *entire block* is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Consequently,

```
if %var% == N (
```

is interpreted as

```
if  == N (
```

which is what the parser is complaining about.

Two issues:

First, if you are entering a string with a `set/p`, then there's no sying that the data entered doesn't contain <kbd>Spaces</kbd>. The way to get over that is to `"enclose the srings on both sides of the comparison operator in quotes"`

Second, since you want to enter the `var` string conditionally, you either need to structure the code differently (so the entry doesn't appear in the code-block) or use `delayed expansion`.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

will allow you to use the syntax `if "!var!"=="whatever including spaces"` to access the CURRENT value of `var` within a block. It's best set directly after the `@echo off` and has the advantage of restoring the environment to its original condition when the batch terminates.